# How do I see which games a battle.net friend owns?

Tags: battle.net

Is it possible to see a list of games a certain friend owns, like in steam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. You can only see what your friends are playing. So by looking at what they play you can deduce what games they have.